# Call v-model from a different component in VueJS

Tags: javascript, vue.js, components

How to call a v-model that is placed in a different component?
The *search* text-field is placed in the **App.vue** and I need to trigger the *:search='search'* in the **Datatable.vue**

App.vue code:

```
    <v-text-field
    v-model="search"
    class="mx-3"
    label="Suche"
    ></v-text-field>
```

Datatable.vue code:

```
<v-data-table
ref='dTable'
:items='products'
:search='search'
class='elevation-1'
>
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

There is a number of different ways you can share data between your components.

In your case, since you have a the `v-text-field` bound to your `search`-data, you can simply pass it along to your `Datatable` component.

```
<div id="app">
  <v-text-field v-model="search" ...  />
  <Datatable v-bind:search="search" ... />
</div>
```

Then you have to "catch" and use it in your `Datatable` component.

---

## Other ways of sharing data:

#### Service bus

One of the ways is creating a `serviceBus`, to emit changes to different parts of your application. Take a look at [this blog post](http://andreybleme.com/2018-01-07/sharing-data-across-vuejs-components/).

In your case, you would set up a listener for `serviceBus.$on('searchInitiated', (query) => { ... })` in your data table component - and in the search component trigger the search by calling `serviceBus.$emit('searchInitiated', this.search)`;

This lets you share component state across different components, independent of hierarchy.

---

#### Passing Data to Child Components with Props

Another way of "sharing data", is letting a "high level component" keep track of your state - then [pass the data on to child components](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Passing-Data-to-Child-Components-with-Props).

This might get cumbersome, if you have a deeply nested component hierarchy - as you have to pass the prop from component to component.

---

#### Sending Messages to Parents with Events

You can also [emit values from a child component](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Sending-Messages-to-Parents-with-Events) (`Search`) to the parent (`App`),  then pass this data on to your `DataTable`.

A variation of the "Service bus" example, differing on that there is no "shared bus" - you have to specifically attach the callback to your child component.

---

#### Share state via `vuex`

You can also utilize [`vuex`](https://vuex.vuejs.org/) to share state between your components. [Here](https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/) is a great guide for getting started.

Comment: Thank you, can I use one "Service bus" for the whole application? (great blog btw.)

Comment: You decide how many buses you might need. Yes, it's a thorough blog post - all creds to the OP :)